# Get n-th character of string : AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement my own `string_view`. Here is an example of class:

```
class Example {
public:
    Example(const std::string& s) : data_(s.data()) {}

    char operator[](size_t pos) const {
        return data_[pos];
    }
private:
    const char* data_;
};
```

Test:

```
Example e("hello");
char t = e[1];
REQUIRE(t == 'e');
```

An error:

```
==38867==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7ffee74544a2 at pc 0x0001087ad931 bp 0x7ffee7454400 sp 0x7ffee74543f8
READ of size 1 at 0x7ffee74544a2 thread T0
    #0 0x1087ad930 in Example::operator[](unsigned long) const code.h:12

Address 0x7ffee74544a2 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 66 in frame
    #0 0x1087aca5f in ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() test.cpp:7

  This frame has 11 object(s):
    [32, 40) 'e' (line 9)
    [64, 88) 'ref.tmp' (line 9) <== Memory access at offset 66 is inside this variable
```

Why do I have this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: The result of `s.data()` can be invalidated. You need to make a copy of that data if you want to use it outside of that immediate constructor scope. Why not keep a `std::string` copy? Not sure what the `const char*` has here in the way of advantages. It's just messy memory management problems waiting to happen.

Comment: @tadman, I am trying to implement my own `string_view`.

Comment: Then you need to make a copy and deal with freeing it in your destructor.

Comment: You are keeping reference to a temp.orary object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I have this error

Because you point to the contents of a temporary `std::string` object that no longer exists and attempt to access the content that no longer exists.

> how can I fix it?

A string view can remain valid only as long as the string is valid. Do not let the `std::string` be destroyed before you are done with the view. Simple fix:

```
std::string str = "hello";
Example e(str);
```

Alternative fix for this case is to do what the standard string view does and add a constructor overload that accepts a pointer to const char:

```
Example::Example(const char*);
```

This way no temporary `std::string` object will be created when you pass a string literal.

---

In general, when you have a problem with re-implementing a standard entity, then it is a good idea to compare how your attempt differs from the standard.

Comment: Is there any other fixes? I cannot change the test, only my implementation.

Comment: Easy: Copy the data! Hint: `strdup`.

Comment: @tadman That's not what "string view" is supposed to do though.

Comment: @demas Either you own the data and can put it in that property, or you don't and you can't. Pick one. One way to assume ownership is to copy it and own the copy.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

class Example {
public:
    // reference to string litteral (notice the constexpr)
    template <size_t N>
    constexpr Example(const char (&s)[N]) noexcept : data_(s), size_(N) {}

    // pointer / size
    Example(const char *begin, size_t sz)
        : data_(begin)
        , size_(sz) {}

    // using iterators
    Example(const char *begin, const char *end)
        : Example{begin, size_t(std::distance(begin, end))} {}

    // reference to another std::string (invalid when the string is destroyed)
    Example(std::string &s) noexcept : data_(s.data()), size_(s.size()) {}

    constexpr char operator[](size_t pos) const {
        return data_[pos];
    }
private:
    const char* data_;
    const std::size_t size_;
};
constexpr Example hello{"hello"};
static_assert(hello[0] == 'h', "");

int main() {
    std::string s = "world";
    Example hello{s};
    return hello[0];
}
```

You are actually creating a new std::string object while invoking your constructor, which is freed when you go out of constructor's scope.
You need to keep a pointer to a string literal `const char (&s)[N]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Example {
public:
    Example(const std::string& s) // s is temporary
         : data_(s.data()) {      // data refers to internal data of s
    }                             // at the ctor exit, s is destroyed

    char operator[](size_t pos) const {
        return data_[pos];        // data_ is invalid
    }
private:
    const char* data_;
};
```

Your constructor takes a string by reference, but you're not passing it a string.  You're passing a literal, which is an array of const char, that converts to a char const*, which can be used to construct a temporary std::string.  This temporary is bound to your constructor parameter, and destroyed when your constructor exits.

In the meanwhile, you're storing a pointer into the data of this temporary object, so when you read through your data pointer, it's referring to internals of a destroyed object.

First, you need to make sure you're not storing a pointer to a temporary.  To do that, you need to restrict your constructor to only work with actual lvalue strings that are passed in.

You can prevent some of this by conversions by making your constructor explicit, and overloading it with another constructor that takes rvalue references to disallow them:

```
class Example {
public:
    explicit Example(const std::string& s) : data_(s.data()) {}                             
    Example(std::string&&) = delete;                             
    ...
};
```

You might also want a constructor that takes a char const* directly.

Now:

```
int main() {
    // error: call to deleted constructor of 'Example'
    Example e1("asdf");
    // error: call to deleted constructor of 'Example'
    Example e2(std::string("asdf"));

    // ok
    std::string str{"asdf"};
    Example e3(str);
}
```

Of course, you should deal with copying, moves, assignments, and the other special functions.

See it live
https://godbolt.org/z/EqjT9o

Comment: I thought about suggesting `Example(std::string&&) = delete;` too, but I was left wondering since the standard string view doesn't do that. Seems like a good idea though.

Comment: `you should deal with copying, moves, assignments, and the other special functions.` The implicitly generated special member functions do what one would want them to do for a string view.

Answer (score 1):

The `string` being passed into your constructor is a temporary and you are storing the pointer returned by its `data()`. The memory that `data()` points to goes away when the temporary `string` does.